# How do i parse the json formate in swift 4 using alamofire

Tags: json, swift4, alamofire, swifty-json

How can parse the JsonObject in Swift 4 using Alamofire?

This is the Json Response:

```
  {"code":"1","ExhibitorData":{"ExhibID":"EXHIB_1","CompanyName":"Star Developers"}}
```

and Below is the Swift Code:

```
  Alamofire.request(Url!, method : .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { response in
         if let JSONResponse = response.result.value as? [String: Any]{
            let Code = JSONResponse["code"] as! [String: Any]
             //How do i parse the data from ExhibitorData here
            }
    }
```

How can I parse the Exhibitor data and store it in variables?

I am new to Swift programming

Comment: Please learn to read JSON. it's pretty easy. **All** values in double quotes are `String` and values in `{}` with String keys and String values are `[String:String]`.

Answer (score -2):

ExhibitorData is in Dictionary formate, so you can use follow code-

```
let ExhibitorData = JSONResponse["ExhibitorData"] as! AnyObject
```